# Do you incur usage costs if someone spams your function URL without the required function key?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My Azure Functions require a function key to access (no, this isn't distributed to the client). In my tests, if I don't supply the key I get back a 401: Not Authorized (good). Is Azure stopping the request before it even gets to my function? Would that then imply that if someone were to try and spam my function URL without the key, that I won't incur any usage costs related to the sudden surge in "demand"? My thought is yes, but I'd like to know if I'm wrong because then I'll need to look into another solution before I go into production.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for this behavior, but my gut tells me that the Functions runtime intercepts the request and since the key is not provided, it does not invoke your Function, thereby not incurring a charge. Closest documentation I could find: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Consumption plan, you are only billed for the time your function actually runs, which **does not** include the time spent by the runtime on authentication prior to dispatching to your function.

While the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) isn't this explicit, it does say:

> Functions are billed based on total number of requested executions each month for all Functions. Executions are counted each time a function is executed in response to an event, triggered by a binding. The first million executions are included free each month.

In this case, your function is never executed (and therefore you are not billed) because authentication failed.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> when an error occurs before your function code begins to execute you aren't charged for an execution. This means that 401 responses from the platform due to API key validation or the App Service Authentication / Authorization feature don't count against your execution cost.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-consumption-costs?tabs=portal